# Making items from previous control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Let's say I have two DataGridViews on my form. The columns in the DGVs are all different. However, the first column of both grid's is called "ProductID". The "ProductID" column is formatted to be a combobox. For the first grid, I am going to default the combobox options to be numbers 1-10. How can I set the second DGV combobox to only have options that were already selected in the first DGV?

So if I filled out two rows of the first DGV and the first ProductID was '1' and the second row was '5', the only option for 'ProductID' on the second DataGridView would be '1' and '5'. Thank you very much, I hope I provided ample information.

Comment: Some code showing how the dgvs are populated would help.

Comment: The DGV's are not populated programmatically. The user provides input via the DGV on the form. The datasource for the DGV's are DataTables which are predefined because I need to generate xml files from them.

Comment: How do the comboboxes get 1, 2, 3, ..., 10 in them?

Comment: On the first DataGridView in the properties I click "Edit Columns..." Then I change the column type to "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" then i edit "Items" and enter in 1,2,3... line by line

Comment: Fine, and I can answer based on this, but you should consider doing that programmatically from some data source.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    Dim vals = DataGridView1.
        Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow).
        Where(Function(r) r.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing).
        Select(Function(r) r.Cells(0).Value).
        Distinct()
    Me.Column2.Items.Clear()
    For Each v In vals
        Me.Column2.Items.Add(v.ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

In the linq:

- Get the rows. Must cast with OfType to get IEnumerable
- Filter by only rows with values
- Select the values (strings)
- Take a distinct subset as not to have two 7's when 7 is selected twice

Then

- Clear any existing items
- Add the items

[image: image:]

DataGridView1 is the one with the 10 IDs in each of the comboboxes in the first column. This is referenced by index in code as index 0 in `r.Cells(0)`

Column1 is the name of the column described above

Column2 is the name of the column in the second DataGridView, where you want to filter the items

There is an exception if you have selected a value in dgv 2, then deselected it in dgv1. Up to you to handle that.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me! Can I ask why I need create the DataGrids programatically? They only need to exist in runtime to input data. The data doesn't need to be stored because it is immediately written to an xml file

Comment: Because you may not always have ProductID 1 through 10. If you add another product, must you recompile your application?!?